# pyautogui, не отображается перемещение мыши

Tags: python, pyautogui

Сижу на Debian, если это на что-то влияет, проблема с библиотекой pyautogui, в частности с функцией moveTo()

```
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100)
```

Данная строчка можно сказать не работает. Когда запускаю код, сама мышка (то что мы видим) остается на том же самом месте. Но она типо в другом месте, когда я пытаюсь что-то сделать с включенным кодом все идет на перекосяк (нормально шрифт не выделяется и т.д.). Запустил код не с мгновенным перемещением, заметил что есть следы как курсор двигается, то есть сам курсор стоял неподвижно, но видно как подсвечивались элементы, как если бы на них навели курсором.

Comment: Скорее всего связано с разрешением, PyAutoGui видит другое разрешение экрана, и советую посмотреть портирована ли библиотека под  Debian, в репозитории например.